# mkmapView gets very slow when zoom out using clustering

Tags: swift, mkmapview

im implementing clustering in my app, when I zoom out, the clustering appears, but the apps performance is getting very bad, the app is getting very slow. event it freezes
the code below:

```
class StoreClusterView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {


    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        clusteringIdentifier = kMapPinName
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            clusteringIdentifier = kMapPinName
        }
    }
}

class StoreAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {//MKAnnotationView

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            clusteringIdentifier = kMapPinName
            customCalloutView?.removeFromSuperview()
            if let pointAnnotation = newValue as? PointAnnotation {
                displayPriority = pointAnnotation.priority
            }
        }
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        clusteringIdentifier = kMapPinName
        displayPriority = .defaultHigh
        self.canShowCallout = false
        updateImage()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.canShowCallout = false
        updateImage()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.customCalloutView?.removeFromSuperview()

        updateImage()
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        // if super passed hit test, return the result
        if let parentHitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) {
            return parentHitView

        } else {
            // test in our custom callout.
            if customCalloutView != nil {
                return customCalloutView!.hitTest(convert(point, to: customCalloutView!), with: event)
            } else {
                return nil

            }
        }
    }
}

extension StoreAnnotationView {

     func updateImage() {
        ....
    } 
}
```

the view controller which contains the mapView and its functions :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
....
 storeMapView.register(StoreAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

                storeMapView.register(StoreClusterView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

        storeMapView.addAnnotations(StoresManager.shared.clusterManager.annotations)
}

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        } else {
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: kMapPinName)
            if annotationView == nil {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    annotationView = StoreAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: kMapPinName)
                }
            } else {
                annotationView!.annotation = annotation
            }
            return annotationView
        }
    }
```

if someone has an idea what's going around, it would be great, thanks

Comment: The `viewFor` method has little issues with it, but do I correctly infer that you’re really targeting iOS 11 and later (given the lack of `if #available(...) { ... } around the `register` calls)? If so, rather than going through and revising `viewFor`, you should jus remove it. That’s the whole point of registering those annotation view classes in iOS 11 and later, so you don’t have to implement that method at all.

Comment: But setting that aside, the basic pattern here is fine. If you’re seeing it slow down (eventually to the point of freezing), I suspect that the problem rests elsewhere, as `MKMapView`’s clustering stuff is pretty solid. Try creating blank project with what you’ve shared with us above (short of removing the aforementioned `viewFor` method) and see if you can reproduce the problem. I don’t think you will.

Comment: I’d suggest using Instruments’ “Time Profiler” tool (perhaps include the “waiting threads” recording option), and see where time is being spent. See [Getting Started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/), if you’re not familiar with this.